# Which username and password should be give in order to connect to database?

Tags: php, mysql, web

I have these usernames and passwords:

User name: `AmirAman`
Pin: `****`
Password: `***************1`
 
Parallels Plesk: `qatarreal`
 
password: `*************2`

DataBase:
username: `amir`
password: *******3

When I type this code in `index.php` file, it doesn't work and Internal Server Error appears:

```
<?php
$username = "AmirAman";
$password = "**********1";
$hostname = "www.qatarreal-estate."; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
 or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
   echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";
```

thank you for this answers , i tried all possible suggestion  , but there are no thing changed , same result appear in this website qatarreal-estate.com.

Comment: `www.qatarreal-estate.` is not a valid hostname

Comment: www.qatarreal-estate. that isn't a correct URL

Comment: use `mysql_error()` to find the real problem.

Comment: use `localhost` for `$hostname`

Comment: @shaunak-Shukla - not if the database is on a different server

Comment: In most of the cases it's security leak to have username for the application, which runs externaly. Either you have local copy of the DB, where you use localhost to interact with the DB on the local server and having the external db, with user again on localhost, which only works when the file is uploaded and ran from the server. So, on your PC you have DB and user connecting to it, and on thr webserver you have DB and user that connects to it. If you run locally - use your local db, if you commit and run externaly - use the external db. Both ran on localhost.

Comment: @Mark Baker - You are right.. but let him/her try once if it is in same server!! :) -- Solution may be $username = "amir"; $password = "***3"; $hostname="localhost";

Comment: thank you for this answers , i tried all possible suggestion  , but there are no thing changed , same result appear in this website qatarreal-estate.com.

Comment: Give me all of them and I’ll try them and let you know which ones to use.

Answer (score 1):

```
DataBase:
username: amir
password: ***3
```

You will need to use these, like the following:

```
$username = "amir";
$password = "***3";
$hostname = "localhost";
```

I'm assuming the hostname of the mysql database is local, due to it not being defined in the information and webhosting providers sometimes leave that information out if it's on localhost.

Also note that you are using mysql_* functions which are considered bad practice and will be removed from PHP in the near future. Better is to use the PDO class or at least mysqli_* functions.

Answer (score 0):

As other people pointed out in the comments, your hostname is wrong. Try this:

```
enter code here

<?php
$username = "AmirAman";
$password = "**********1";
$hostname = "qatarreal-estate.com"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
 or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
   echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";
```

Assuming `qatarreal-estate.com`is the domain you are looking for.

Edit: If you run the MySQL server locally, use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` for the hostname.